# Pandas conditional rolling counter between 2 columns of boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, count, rolling-computation

thanks in advance for helping a python newbie like me.

I would like to achieve the following results in the column "count" without using a stupid slow for loop.

I am sure it is possible to vectorize that. Any suggestions ?

Thanks again !

```
       A       B       count
    0  False   False     0
    1  True    False     1
    2  False   False     1 
    3  True    False     2
    4  False   True      1 # True value in the other column: reset the counter
    5  False   False     1
    6  True    False     1 # True value in the other column: reset the counter
    7  False   True      1 # True value in the other column: reset the counter
    8  False   True      2
    9  False   False     2
   10  False   True      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['count'] = (df.groupby(df.A.cumsum())['B'].cumsum() + df.groupby(df.B.cumsum())['A'].cumsum())
```

OUTPUT:

```
        A      B  count
0   False  False      0
1    True  False      1
2   False  False      1
3    True  False      2
4   False   True      1
5   False  False      1
6    True  False      1
7   False   True      1
8   False   True      2
9   False  False      2
10  False   True      3
```

Comment: Absolut sick fast and correct answer. Thank you so much ! What was your thought process to be so quick ?